# Problema docker-compose.yml en Debian 11

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Para ponerlos en contexto, estoy realizando una aplicación en Springboot utilizando Docker y a la hora de hacer un compose del archivo **docker-compose.yml** tengo un error ya que no encuentro los contenedores nisiquiera dentro del **Docker Desktop** a continuación les dejo el archivo, resulta que estoy en linux, mas precisamente en Debian 11. El mismo **docker-compose.yml** fue corrido esta mañana en windows y funcióno sin problema alguno.

```
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo_db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo_express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  mongo: {}
```

Esto es lo que me sale luego de algunos comandos en linux:

```
$ ls
                                                                                                                              
docker-compose.yml  mvnw  mvnw.cmd  pom.xml  src
```

Aca trato de hacer un compose nomrla y me tira ese error

```
$ docker-compose up -d    
                                                                                                        
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

Luego corriendolo como sudo no tengo ningun tipo de problema

```
$ sudo docker-compose up -d                                                                                                       [sudo] password for ags: 
Creating mongo_db      ... done
Creating mongo_express ... done
```

Pero si veo los container sin sudo obtengo esto

```
$ docker ps                                                                                                                       
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

Pero una vez siendo super usuario los encuentra, pero no puedo ingresar al localhost:8081 ya que segundo docker no existe

```
$ sudo su                                                                                                                         
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                           NAMES
c4f319f13fc9   mongo-express   "/sbin/tini -- /dock…"   9 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp, :::8081->8081/tcp       mongo_express
2141932d7734   mongo           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   mongo_db
```

```
$ sudo docker context ls
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *           moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Mi objetivo final es poder ver los contenedores dentro del Docker Desktop y poder ingresar normalmente al localhost:8081 donde se encuentra la base de datos, cosa que a la mañana pude hacer en windows.

Comment: El primer error *Couldn't connect to Docker daemon...* es porque no tienes corriendo el servicio de docker, que si o si lo tenes que levantar como su. Luego, para levantar los contenedores del docker-compose con tu usuario (en vez del su), tendrias que agregar tu usuario a un grupo `docker`. Esta todo explicado en la documentacion https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: Apenas llegue a mi casa voy a probar eso, en estos momento me encuento en Linux y al correr el archivo funciona pero cuando voy al localhost:8081 me pide las credenciales lo normal, ingreso "root" y "root" asi como está definido en el compose y no funciona, alguna idea?